# Error in if (temp < vmin) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, markov-decision-process

I am trying to code the Markov Chain approximation for some control problems.
But I have the following bug in R and I checked similar question in Stackoverflow and still have
no idea how to solve it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The bug comes from where I would like to find the minimum value among all of 'u' in a for loop.

To specific, in the `uit-for-loop`, for each next `uit` I could get a new single value (I thought) `temp` and would like to compare this with the temporary minimal stored by a single value variable `vmin`. That is the idea in the `if-else` sentence.

It is better to skip the parameter setting and initialization procedure.

```
#----- parameters ------
xleft=0; xright=10
yleft=0; yright=10
h=0.01
Nx=(xright-xleft)/h
Ns=2
Nu=11; hu=0.2
la=0.1
qMainDiag=c(-0.5,-0.5)
qSubDiag=c(0.5,0.5)
alpha=c(0.2,0.25)
beta=c(0.35,0.2)
a=c(0.6,0.8)
b=c(0.5,0.3)
c=c(0.45,0.5)
d=c(0.65,0.8)
tol=10^(-8)
maxitr=10000
#---- Initialization -----
Vold=array(0,dim=c(Nx+1,Nx+1,Ns))
Vnew=array(0,dim=c(Nx+1,Nx+1,Ns))
Uopt=array(0,dim=c(Nx+1,Nx+1,Ns))
for(r in 1:Ns){
  for(i in 1:(Nx+1)){
    for(j in 1:(Nx+1)){
      Vold[i,j,r]=1
    }
  }
}
#---- iteration ----
for(n in 1:maxitr){
  for(r in 1:Ns){
    # inner of O
    for(i in 2:Nx){
      for(j in 2:Nx){
        vInt=0
        for(it in 1:(min(i,j)+1)){
          vInt=vInt+Vold[i-it+1,j-it+1,r]*0.1*exp(-0.1*(it-1)*h)*h
        }
        # For each u, want to find the minimum temp value and its u.
        for(uit in 1:Nu){
          x=xleft+(i-1)*h; y=yleft+(j-1)*h
          u=hu*(uit-1)
          Xi11=(alpha[r]*x)^2; Xi22=(beta[r]*y)^2
          f1=x*(a[r]-b[r]*y+u); f2=y*(-c[r]+d[r]*x+u)
          g=1+r*(x+y)*(1+u^2)
          Qh=(Xi11+Xi22)+h*(abs(f1)+abs(f2))+h-(h^2)*qMainDiag[r]
          dlt=(h*h)/Qh
          pforward=0.5*(Xi11+2*h*max(f1,0.0))/Qh
          pback=0.5*(Xi11+2*h*max(-f1,0.0))/Qh
          pup=0.5*(Xi22+2*h*max(f2,0.0))/Qh
          pdown=0.5*(Xi22+2*h*max(-f2,0.0))/Qh
          pswitch=(h*h*qSubDiag[r])/Qh
          pstay=h/Qh
          temp=(1-la*dlt)*(pforward*Vold[i+1,j,r]+pback*Vold[i-1,j,r]
                           +pup*Vold[i,j+1,r]+pdown*Vold[i,j-1,r]
                           +pswitch*Vold[i,j,3-r]
                           +pstay*Vold[i,j,r])+la*dlt*vInt+dlt*g
          # find the minimal value (Here is the spot!!!)
          if(uit==1){
            vmin=temp; umin=u
          }else if(temp<vmin){
            vmin=temp; umin=u
          }
        }
        Vnew[i,j,r]=vmin
        Uopt[i,j,r]=umin
      }
    }
    errormax=max(abs(Vold-Vnew))
    print(n)
    print(errormax)
    Vold=Vnew
    if(errormax<tol){
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The values stored within the variable `temp` inside the `for-loop`, produces a matrix `[0, 0]`, with `numeric(0)`, this is an empty vector where `if else` assume it to be empty, therefore you must create it into a boolean structure using ```isTrue(temp<vmin)```, however you then get another error which you will have to solve, that is similar to the one that you got for this. The problem is that you keep storing empty vectors into other variables, is this what you want?

Comment: To fix the next error, you can do `Vnew[i,j,r] = length(vmin)` this seems to run the loop correctly for me

Comment: @Stackbeans   Thank you so much for the reply. I am new to R and what I meant is that `temp` is just a single value and `for-loop` will calculate the minimal `temp` stored as another single valued variable called `vmin` among all of `uit`. Are you meaning that `temp` will store all of values as a matrix for `uit` rather than be assigned by the new computed value when `uit` increases 1?